# Unable to call an Action from component in reactjs(typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I am trying to call an action from my Function but all I am getting is this ,I have Used the same method in my other component and it works fine there and I don't know what I am doing wrong here

```
    this.props.getPosts is not a function
    at AddtodoForm.componentWillMount (AddtodoForm.tsx:30)
    at callComponentWillMount (react-dom.development.js:13985)
    at mountClassInstance (react-dom.development.js:14084)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17771)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:19381)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:363)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:412)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:466)
    at beginWork$$1 (react-dom.development.js:24570)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:23502)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:23480)
    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:23155)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:22653)
    at scheduleRootUpdate (react-dom.development.js:25686)
    at updateContainerAtExpirationTime (react-dom.development.js:25712)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:25812)
    at react-dom.development.js:26370
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:22952)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:26369)
    at render (react-dom.development.js:26460)
    at Module../src/index.tsx (index.tsx:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.0 (index.tsx:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
```

My AddtodoForm code is

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { AddPostModel } from '../model/dataModels';
import {PostNewPost,getPosts} from '../actions/types';
export interface IProps{
    updateTodo?: Object
};
export interface IState{
    title : string,
    newTitle :string
};
interface IDispatchProp {
    getPosts:() => void;
}
type Props = & IProps & IDispatchProp  
export class AddtodoForm extends React.Component<Props,IState>{
    constructor(props :Props,state: IState){
            super(props)
        state={
           title : '',
           newTitle : ''
        }
    }
    onChange = (e : any) => {  
        this.setState({ title : e.target.value});
    }

    addtodoItem =() => {

        const add = this.state.title

        AddPostModel.id = add;


    } 
    render(){
        return(
                <div>              
                <input onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Add todo"/>
                <br/>
                <button onClick={() => this.props.getPosts()}> Add todo</button>
                <br/>
                <br/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch : any) => ({

    getPosts:() => dispatch(getPosts())
  });
export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(AddtodoForm);
```

**And In my Actions I am just returning type specific to every function Called 
 and then goes to the reducer and returns the state**

```
import { todo} from '../models/todo';
import { deleteModel } from '../model/dataModels';

export enum ActionTypes {
    ADD_TODO = '[todos] ADD_TODO',  
    GET_TODO = '[todos] GET_TODO',
    CHECK_CONNECTION = '[todos] CHECK_CONNECTION',
    ERROR = 'ERROR',
    DELETE_TODO = 'DELETE_TODO',
    UPDATE_TODO = 'UPDATE_TODO',
    LOAD_IMAGES = 'LOAD_IMAGES',
    ADD_NEW_POST = 'ADD_NEW_POST'
  }

export interface AddTodoAction { type: ActionTypes, payload: any }

export const loadImages = () => (console.log('here'),{
  type: ActionTypes.LOAD_IMAGES
});

export const getPosts = ( posts ?: any) => ( console.log('I am in getPostAction'),{
  type: ActionTypes.GET_TODO,
  payload: posts,
});
export const PostNewPost = () => (console.log('I am posting new poost'),{
  type : ActionTypes.ADD_NEW_POST
})
export const DeletTodo = () => ( console.log(deleteModel.id),{
  type: ActionTypes.DELETE_TODO,
  payload : deleteModel.id
});
```

Comment: Seems like you're not giving us the whole story. Your error message says it happened in `componentWillMount` but your code doesn't have a `componentWillMount` method.

Comment: I tried to call the Action in componentWillMount its showed the same error then I tried to call it in a function but its still the same

Comment: Get a working example of this problem in codesandbox.io and the solution will be found.

Answer (score -1):

```
import {PostNewPost, getPosts: getPostsRequest} from '../actions/types';

//.... 
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch : any) => ({  
 getPosts:() => dispatch(getPostsRequest()) 
});
```

I think you should try rename your action :D

Comment: That's not a problem here, as they are not creating any other variable with the name `getPosts`